# $this lost focus after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have following CakePHP code :

```
<tr class="tr_clone">
      <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('items][',array('label'=>false,'options'=>$items,'class'=>'items')); ?> </td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('price][',array('class'=>'price','label'=>false)) ?></td><td><?php echo $this->Form->input('unit][',array('class'=>'unit','label'=>false)) ?></td>
</tr>
```

Where my `.tr_clone` is cloned using jQuery. 
Following HTML is generated after rendering HTML and after cloning `.tr_clone` data one time.

```
    <table>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
       <td>
          <div class="input select">
           <select id="InvoiceItems][" class="items" name="data[Invoice][items][]">
           <option value="3">Item1</option>
           <option value="4">Item2</option>
           <option value="5">Item3</option>
           </select>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="input text">
           <input type="text" id="InvoicePrice][" class="price" name="data[Invoice][price][]">
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="input text">
           <input type="text" id="InvoiceUnit][" class="unit" name="data[Invoice][unit][]">
         </div>
       </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr_clone">
       <td>
          <div class="input select">
           <select id="InvoiceItems][" class="items" name="data[Invoice][items][]">
           <option value="3">Item1</option>
           <option value="4">Item2</option>
           <option value="5">Item3</option>
           </select>
          </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="input text">
           <input type="text" id="InvoicePrice][" class="price" name="data[Invoice][price][]">
         </div>
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class="input text">
           <input type="text" id="InvoiceUnit][" class="unit" name="data[Invoice][unit][]">
         </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now I am sending an AJAX request when `focusout` event occurs on `select`. After successful completion of AJAX request I want to populate my `.price` field.

The problem is that when I am sending AJAX request I am unable to focus again on next element after select i.e. `.price` and fill it with returned value.

Following is my jQuery Code:

```
$("table").on('focusout','.items',function(){
      var id=$('.items option:selected').val();   
      $.ajax({
        method:'POST',
        url:"get_price",
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(result){           
               $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find('.price').text(result));
        }
      });
});
```

Here is [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BxLMu/1/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need `proxy()` your success function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `success` callback context is the `ajaxSettings` object. That means that `this` inside this callback function will return `$.ajaxSettings`.

If you want to change the context of the `success` callback, for example for `this` to give you the DOM element, specify corresponding ajax option:

```
$("table").on('focusout','.items',function(){
  var id=$('.items option:selected').val();
  $.ajax({
    context: this, // <- equals to $("table")
    method:'POST',
    url:"get_price",
    data:{id:id},
    success:function(result){           
           $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find('.price').text(result));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have same class for every cloned row. So I am unable to do. Otherwise it is easy.

Comment: @Echo, edited with a clearer explanation. Does this make sense now?

Comment: Thanks for context part :). It helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Andrei is getting at is your context of `this` changes inside your function

```
success:function(result){           
    $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find('.price').text(result));
}
```

The problem is `this` now refers to your anonymous function when you want it to refer to your `jQuery` object. So what we need to do is [proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) the context we want

```
$("table").on('focusout','.items',$.proxy(function(){
  var id=$('.items option:selected').val();
  $.ajax({
    context: this, // <- equals to $("table")
    method:'POST',
    url:"get_price",
    data:{id:id},
    success:$.proxy(function(result){           
    $(this).closest('.tr_clone').find('.price').text(result));
    }, this)
  });
}, this));
```

Now your `this` reference should refer to the proper `jQuery` object

Comment: but it is not populating .price

Comment: Hmm, maybe need to wrap the next level up in `proxy` as well